# Do new responsibilites mean new job title or should this be only a remark in ones CV?

Tags: management, resume, title, teamleader

**current state**

I am a software engineer, which is also the official job title I applied for. I got some certifications which officially enables me to train apprentices. On my CV those certifications are listed with other certifications.

Usually I get projects which I work on by myself or with another software engineer. Recently though I got a whole new project with a lot more responsibilites.

**what changed**

So the company wants to buy a new systemplugin, which enhances our in-house software. Like the software salesmen use etc. The in-house software is also bought, but has been modified with selfmade plugins.

My responsibility now is that I take care that the new system gets implemented smoothly without our workers noticing. Which also means that the modifications we made must be present in the new plugin. Some are already built in, some need to be built with that new plugin. Takes some work as the old plugins were written with C++ and the new plugin is based on vue. I would also be the person that workers contact if they need modifications, the person that talks to the company providing the plugin and other software engineers would also work on the new plugin and report to me. I also got another engineer who acts as my assistant.

**question**

So what I was wondering now: does this fit any job title? I mean I wouldnt be a PM or PO.
If this does not justify another job title, how would I write it on my CV?

Why is it important? Well this would justify a pay raise obviously. But I also want to switch jobs in the next 5 years and want my CV to reflect what I am capable of, maybe even get a job in management, which is not possible where I am now. At least I wouldnt get the title officially and the pay.

Comment: I see two questions here: One is an internal question about job titles & pay raise and an external question without how to present this on a CV.  Both of these have potential to be good questions, but with them being in the same question makes it harder to give a good complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is up to your employer, because it depends on internal job responsibilities - I cannot tell you if your company considers what you do to be one job title or another. If they gave you these projects without a promotion, its safe to say they don't see them as promotion-worthy - although you can always ask your manager about it. If you are asking whether *we* think that these responsibilities warrant a new job title, I would say no. I am not a software engineer, but the technical aspects you are describing sound like just a technically challenging project under your job title. Other titles like a project manager might be appropriate if you had several engineers working under you. I would simply list these newfound responsibilities under your current role on your CV.

If you are very committed to title jumps, talk to your manager and see if you can find out what they need to see from you in order to give you a promotion. If they can not give you a roadmap to a title bump, sounds like you may not be satisfied there for much longer.

Comment: There also may be changes in title that can be made without promotion or changing what you're doing. When I was working in the research division, I got myself reclassified  from "programmer" to "scientist" -- the change meant almost nothing formally but I always wanted to be a scientist when I grew up so it amused me, and might or might not have been a bit more eye-catching on a resume. (In fact I've always been an engineer rather than a scientist, but as a kid I didn't know the difference.)

Answer (score 3):

#### Stop worrying about titles and focus on skills and accomplishments

Titles don't mean anything in general and mean less in software.  Do you think you would get hired on if your title were Vice President of vue?

Every new thing you do will not result in a title change.

Comment: I second this. People are not hired because of job titles, but because of the value of work they provide. Job titles are even a form of compensation when the work itself is dull and boring. Look at the hierarchical structures and ranks in (normal) banks.